# Using the ContactPicker contract when snapped

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Can I use the [ContactPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR224913) contract when the app is snapped?

```
var picker = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactPicker();
picker.CommitButtonText = "Select";
picker.SelectionMode = Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.ContactSelectionMode.Fields;
picker.DesiredFields.Add(Windows.ApplicationModel.Contacts.KnownContactField.Email);
var contactInformation = await picker.PickSingleContactAsync();
```

The above code works when in fullscreen but throws the following exception on the call to PickSingleContactAsync() when snapped to the side of the screen:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled by user code
>
> HResult=-2147467259
>
> Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> Source=mscorlib
>
> ErrorCode=-2147467259
>
> StackTrace:
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task  task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>          at TouchToneDtmf.MainPage.d__e.MoveNext()
>   in
>   d:\Users\Foo\MainPage.xaml.cs:line
>   556   InnerException:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working when the app is snapped - you should check the visual state of the app before calling the ContactPicker.

In the official C# sample there is also method EnsureUnsnapped() you might find helpful when implementing this contract.

> Every time you call a file[/contact] picker you must first make sure that your
>   app can show the file[/contact] picker by verifying that your app in not snapped
>   or, if your app is snapped, that it can be unsnapped in order to show
>   the file picker. [Source - How to save files through file pickers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx)

```
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
//...
internal bool EnsureUnsnapped()
{
    bool unsnapped = ((ApplicationView.Value != ApplicationViewState.Snapped) || ApplicationView.TryUnsnap());
    return unsnapped;
}
```